# I can`t enter values when I run my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
void Manager::ManagerView1()
{
    system("cls");
    string Ipass;
    string Opass;
    ifstream Password("Password.txt", ios::in);
    if (!Password)
    {
        cerr << "Check File Integrity";
    }
    else
    {
        while (!Password.eof())
        {
            getline(Password,Ipass);
            cout << "Enter Password :\n";
            cin >> Opass;

            if (Opass == Ipass)
            {
                cout << "Passwords Match";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Text inside the "Password.txt":

> Abhik Ray 1123

The password is being read properly, I have already checked that.

When I run the code it lets me enter the password but then the Passwords match doesn't show up as it should. And then it again asks for the password where I am unable to enter it. And then it just quits.

What should I change?

Comment: Is "Abhik Ray 1123" the password, or is "Abhik Ray" the username and "1123" the password?

Comment: Abhik Ray 1123 is the password

Comment: You need to use `std::string` instead of `char[]`

Comment: Ok but my main question is why am i unable to enter Opass for comparison . I mean i do need to enter it to compare but i can`t enter it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems, like trying to match only one line from the password file at a time.

The reason for the message is that `if (Opass == Ipass)` compares the addresses of the character arrays, not their contents.

If you had used `std::string` to store the strings, the comparison would have worked, but with C style strings you need to use `if(strcmp(Opass, Ipass) == 0)`.

You might also want to check this question for how to terminate the loop:

[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

---

In the new version of the code with `cin >> Opass;` the `>>` will only read one word at a time (it stops at each space). So if you type `Abhik Ray 1123` you will only get `Abhik` in `Opass`, and the rest of the line will remain in the input buffer until the next read.

That's also why it doesn't ask for the next input, it just reads the following words that are already there.

To read a whole line of input, you need to use `getline(cin, Opass);`, just like when you read from the textfile.

Comment: I can`t enter Opass. How do i so that ??

Answer (score 0):

Opass and Ipass are pointers and by doing `Opass == Ipass` you check if they point to the same area in the memory.
You have to use `strcmp` to compare their values.

Comment: well that`s okay but the main problem is that i can`t even enter Opass

Comment: did you try cin >> Opass?